# Windows 7 computer cannot delete files from windows 2003 domain share

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, domain

Computer running windows 7 pro connected to windows 2003 domain. User creates an xls file and he is trying to delete it. He deletes the file successfully and when he presses F5 to refresh the folder the file re-appears like it was never deleted.

Comment: Is it a permissions issue?  Does the user have the right to delete files?

Comment: no permissions issue. user can delete/create/modify files and folders in other shared folders. the problem is only in a specific folder. It is weird thought. Maybe its a windows7 windows 2003 thing?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any kind of file protection software (aftermarket) on the Windows 7 machine?  Such software might view the deletion to be unauthorized (by rule) and simply restore it.  The Win2003 user wouldn't be aware of it from viewing the share.  Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion there is some administrative privileges issue. Please check whether this issue is with xls file only or with other files also.